# What is the name and meaning of a World War 2 CCC Medal with both the Polish Eagle and British Statant Gardant Lion?

Tags: world-war-two, military, britain, poland

While looking through a collection of World War 2 medals, I came across this one (picture attached) and have been unable to identify it.

[image]

It is in the form of a shield, appears to have a Polish eagle in the top left and the British lion from the Victoria Cross on the bottom right. It also has the letters "CCC" along the top.

**Can anyone identify the name and meaning of a World War 2 CCC Medal with both the Polish Eagle and British Statant Gardant Lion?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This would appear to be the badge of the [No. 300 Polish Bomber Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._300_Polish_Bomber_Squadron) which

> fought alongside the Royal Air Force and operated from airfields in
>   the United Kingdom.

[image]

*Above: Badge with colour. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PSP_Dywizjon_300.jpg).  Below, badge (no colouring) on memorial plaque. Source: [Aircrew Remembered](http://aircrewremembered.com/kracinski-henryk.html)*

[image]

The [**CCC** is **300** in Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Air_Forces_in_France_and_Great_Britain) and the badge

> combines the coats of arms of both Poland and England - it has the
>   Polish White Eagle "Orzeł Biały" (an eagle argent armed, crowned) and
>   it has the English Lion (a lion passant guardant, crowned).

The squadron was created in July 1940 and disbanded in February 1947. They flew [Fairey Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Battle) light bombers until November 1940, then [Wellington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_Wellington) bombers until March 1944 and finally [Avro Lancaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Lancaster) bombers.

There is a website dedicated to the squadron [here](http://www.polishsquadronsremembered.com/300/300Squadron.html) with a lot more information than the Wikipedia pages. Among the many targets they bombed was [Berchtesgaden](http://www.polishsquadronsremembered.com/300/Berchtesgaden.html), Hitler's retreat.